# CSS converting pseudo elements to class name

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an ios styled switch button which is created using pseudo classes. I want the active pseudo class here to be converted to normal `.active` class so that I can use it in PHP to activate the button using `if...else` statement like `if(condition) { echo "active"; }`. The problem here is that I am not being able to understand how to make changes in my switch's css to achieve this. I am afraid that I will end up ruining the working CSS right now.

```css
.tgl {
  display: none;
}
.tgl, .tgl:after, .tgl:before, .tgl *, .tgl *:after, .tgl *:before, .tgl + .tgl-btn {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.tgl::-moz-selection, .tgl:after::-moz-selection, .tgl:before::-moz-selection, .tgl *::-moz-selection, .tgl *:after::-moz-selection, .tgl *:before::-moz-selection, .tgl + .tgl-btn::-moz-selection {
  background: none;
}
.tgl::selection, .tgl:after::selection, .tgl:before::selection, .tgl *::selection, .tgl *:after::selection, .tgl *:before::selection, .tgl + .tgl-btn::selection {
  background: none;
}
.tgl + .tgl-btn {
  outline: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 4em;
  height: 2em;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.tgl + .tgl-btn:after, .tgl + .tgl-btn:before {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
.tgl + .tgl-btn:after {
  left: 0;
}
.tgl + .tgl-btn:before {
  display: none;
}
.tgl:checked + .tgl-btn:after {
  left: 50%;
}
.tgl-ios + .tgl-btn {
  background: #fbfbfb;
  border-radius: 2em;
  padding: 2px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
.tgl-ios + .tgl-btn:after {
  border-radius: 2em;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  transition: left 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275), padding 0.3s ease, margin 0.3s ease;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
.tgl-ios + .tgl-btn:hover:after {
  will-change: padding;
}
.tgl-ios + .tgl-btn:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2em #fd267d;
}
.tgl-ios + .tgl-btn:active:after {
  padding-right: 0.8em;
}
.tgl-ios:checked + .tgl-btn {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #ff7854 30%, #fd267d 100%);
}
.tgl-ios:checked + .tgl-btn:active {
  box-shadow: none;
}
.tgl-ios:checked + .tgl-btn:active:after {
  margin-left: -0.8em;
}
```

```html
<form action="processes/settings.php" method="post">
  <input class="tgl tgl-ios singleActions" id="cb2" type="checkbox"/>
  <label class="tgl-btn float-right" for="cb2"></label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:I figured out what you were after.
It's not a css issue.
Just add 'checked' to the input field as an attribute.
Then the styles will be applied

Comment: Tried.. Doesn't seem to do the task. Something else gets distorted after doing it.

Comment: Oh.. I get it now.. I added checked and it's now working. How stupid of me not realizing that I need to put checked as an attribute to the checkbox type. Thanks dude! You had my back. :)

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me and putting back the question.
I've edited my response to include our discussion.
Please give me the upvote.

Comment: I can't upvote as I don't have enough reputation points. But I have accepted it.